# no results shown when I enter the if statement

Tags: php, html

This is the part of the PHP code I am having the issue:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM clients where idcard = '$idcard'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
  or die("Error quering database.");

if(mysqli_fetch_array($result) == False) echo "Sorry, no clients found";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $list = $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'] . " " . $row['address'] . " " . $row['town'] . " " . $row['telephone'] . " " . $row['mobile'];
   echo "<br />";
   echo $list;
}
```

Even if I insert an existing idcard value I get no output when there is the if statement, an incorrect idcard displays "Sorry, no clients found" fine. However if I remove the if statement if I enter an existing idcard the data displays ok.

Can you let me know what is wrong with the code please ?

Thanks

Comment: try using `mysqli_num_rows($result)==0` instead. Also your code has one `{`, but not `}`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `mysqli_num_rows` to count the results:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) echo "Sorry, no clients found";
```

Answer (score 2):

`mysqli_fetch_array()` fetches an item from the database.

This means your `if()` code fetches a first item from the database.

Then, when you call `mysqli_fetch_array()` again from the `while()` condition, **the first item has already been fetched**, and you are trying to fetch the second one ; which does not exist.

You must ensure that you use the result from `mysqli_fetch_array()` and not call it one time just *for nothing* ; or, as an alternative, you could use the [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) function *(quoting)* :

> Returns the number of rows in the result set.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM clients where idcard = '$idcard'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
  or die("Error quering database.");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, no clients found";
}else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       $list = $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'] . " " . $row['address'] . " " . $row['town'] . " " . $row['telephone'] . " " . $row['mobile'];

        echo $list . "<br />";
    }

}
```

Try this.

EDITED: Added closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_num_rows()` to test if there is anything returned.

Answer (score -1):

Imagine you put some money in your pocket.
Eventually an idea came to your mind to see if you are still have the money.
You are taking it out and count them. All right.
*Still holding them in hand* you decided to take them from pocket. Oops! The pocket is empty!

That's your problem.

To see if you got any rows from the database you can use `mysqli_num_rows()`. It will return the number of bills, without fetching them from the pocket.

Comment: I like the simple explanation !

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, that you try to use `mysqli_fetch_array` to queck for the number of results. `mysqli_fetch_array` will fetch the first result, compare it to false and then discard it. The next `mysqli_fetch_array` will then fetch the second result, which is not existing.

If you want to check if any clients where found, you can use `mysqli_num_rows` like this:

```
$idcard = mysqli_escape_string($dbc, $idcard); // See below: Prevents SQL injection
$query = "SELECT * FROM clients where idcard = '$idcard'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("Error quering database.");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, no clients found";
} else {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     // Do whatever you want
  }
}
```

If `$idcard` is a user supplied value, please look out for **SQL injection attacks**.

Comment: what if $idcard is not a user supplied value?

Comment: Except for cross site scripting, server side vulnerabilities in software not written by OP, social engineering, social engineering of the hoster, DNS cache manipulation, ... There are a few thousand ways to hack him. But at least it's not gonna happen by SQL injection in that exact line of code. Am I right?

Comment: Would you be so kind and tell me why?

Comment: it's not a shame when one don't know something. But it's a shame when one refuse to learn...

Comment: Before I start insulting you, would you please read your comments again? You are not telling me anywhere, what I should learn in your opinion.

Comment: One would hope that the OP does checks and sanitizes before proceeding